# Command to run: ls -l . '{' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, ls

I have such code in file hello.py:

```
import sys
import os
import commands

def listdir(dir):
  cmd = 'ls -l ' + dir
  print ("Command to run:", cmd)   ## good to debug cmd before actually running it
  (status, output) = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
  if status:    ## Error case, print the command's output to stderr and exit
    sys.stderr.write(output)
    sys.exit(1)
  print (output)  ## Otherwise do something with the command's output


def main():

 listdir(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I run it from cmd like:

```
$ hello.py .
```

But got error:

```
Command to run: ls -l .
'{' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Could someone help me to refine what is the problem with my code (I got it from google tutorials). python version is 2.7

Comment: Note that `commands` is deprecated since version 2.6 and has been removed in Python 3. Use the `subprocess` module instead. I take it that you are using this as a learning experience and are aware of the existence of [os.listdir()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm)

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? The exact wording of the error message suggests you are. The `commands` module does not work on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From python Standard Library manual :

```
commands.getstatusoutput(cmd) 
Execute the string cmd in a shell with os.popen() and return a 2-tuple (status, output).
cmd is actually run as { cmd ; } 2>&1, so that the returned output will contain output or
error messages. A trailing newline is stripped from the output. The exit status for the
command can be interpreted according to the rules for the C function wait().
```

The syntax `{}` is correctily interpreted by Linux or other Unix like shells, but not by Windows `cmd.exe`.

As others suggested to, try to use `subprocess` ... and read the manual ...